# MariaDB 10 Galera Cluster or Downgrade?

Tags: cluster-computing, mariadb, multi-master-replication

i have some questions about MariaDB. Maybe anyone can help me.
I have two servers and want to loadbalance via DNS (Round Robin). Round Robin is configured. 
Now i want to setup a multi master replication with MariaDB. The Problem that i have is i already have installed on the first server MariaDB in the version 10, but i saw that MariaDB Galera Cluster is only available for 5.5. What would be the best way to setup the MariaDB Galera Cluster? Downgrade or is a Cluster Version for 10 available?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar realization recently.  MariaDB 10 is really nice but there is currently no stable release with galera.  There is an [alpha release (10.0.7)](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-galera-cluster-1007-release-notes/) and it looks like a stable release may be available relatively soon.  For now, though, you should use the 5.5 line.